# Error when creating function to find the largest element in a list

Tags: f#

I wish to create a function that return the largest value in a given list, Here is what I did:

```
let findMax aalist: 'a list=
    let rec helper (l:'a list,m:'a)=
        match m,l with
        |m,li::lf-> if compare m li<0 then helper (lf,li)
                    else helper (lf,m) 
        |m,[] -> m
    helper(aalist, aalist.Head )
```

But I get errors when trying to run the function :

[image]

I don't know if this is the best way to create this function. Please help.

Comment: It looks like you meant `if li > m then helper (lf, li) ...`, `match` is a keyword. You will also need to add a `comparison` constraint to the type parameter `'a` and what to do if the input list is empty.

Comment: I edited the code and will edit the question, I still get error when trying the function on an integer list.

Comment: You need to fix the return type to `a'` instead of `'a list`: `let findMax aalist: 'a`. You can remove all the explicit type annotations and they will be inferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your declaration of the parameter.

This:

```
let findMax aalist: 'a list=
```

should be:

```
let findMax (aalist: 'a list) =
```

When no parenthesis are used the compiler thinks you are specifying the return type of the function. If the return type is `'a list` then the parameter `aalist` must be a list of lists: `'a list list`.

If you do not specify any types at all, the compiler correctly deduces the type of `findMax` as `'a list -> 'a`.

The rule is always specify parameter types within parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `list` type annotation, so you have this:

```fs
let findMax aalist: 'a =
    let rec helper (l:'a list,m:'a) =
        match m,l with
        | m,li::lf -> if li > m then helper (lf,li)
                        else helper (lf,m) 
        | m,[] -> m
    helper(aalist, aalist.Head)
```